# Query to sum calls

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have table contain call durations of a telecom company.

ex:
Table 1

```
| callerid | receiverid  | call duration
| 1        | 2           | 5
| 1        | 2           | 2
| 2        | 3           | 4
| 1        | 5           | 2
```

i need to query above table so the result table after query:

Table 2

```
| callerid | receiverid  | call duration
| 1        | 2           | 7
| 2        | 3           | 4
| 1        | 5           | 2
```

Comment: Please explain the logic. It looks like columns 6, 7, 8 & 9 totalling 10 are replaced by a column with a value of 7?

Comment: I fixed the question

Answer (score 1):

use below

```
select callerid, receiverid, sum(call_duration) call_duration
from your_table
group by callerid, receiverid
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]